# add image into TextInput using Flex4 and action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Hi kindly help me to add .png image into current cursor position of TextInput using Flex 4 and action script 3. I have googled, but I am unable to get correct idea from there. kindly any one suggest me some ideas for add a image into TextInput. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a new TextFlow child/instance which displays the image. Find some infos on that topic [here (livedocs@adobe.com - Adding images with TLF)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ff4.html)

Comment: thanks for reply., using this method, I can add 1 image into textinput. Is there is any option to add more than one image into textInput. for example, in text chat we can add more than 1 smileys at a time.

Comment: Did you try simply adding more InlineGraphicElements?